# Getting the newest email from gmail with pop3

Tags: c#-4.0, pop3

I want to get the newest email from Gmail, but I cannot get it with this program.
I have a new email from Gmail, but my program shows another email.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor cr = Cursor.Current;
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
        tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);
        System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
        sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");                 
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
        sw.WriteLine("USER MyGmail");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.WriteLine("PASS MyGmailPass");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.WriteLine("STAT");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.WriteLine("RETR 1\r\n");
        sw.Flush();
     }
           }
```

Comment: please see these two liks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026101/imap-encoded-emails and https://kevinthant.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/coding-imap-email-access-using-asp-netc/

Comment: Neither one of those links is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `RETR` command is used to download the message at the specified index (1-based, not 0-based).

`RETR 1` retrieves the first (aka the oldest) message in the message spool, not the most recent.

If you want the *latest* email to arrive in your GMail account, you'll need to first find out how many messages you have in your spool.

Can I ask why you are trying to write your own program like this instead of using a library such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)? It would make your life tremendously easier.